# iOS - PHP Uploading UIImage to Localhost

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, uiimage, mamp

I am trying to upload an image file from my iOS app to MAMP ( localhost ), i have been struggling in this problem for a week till now

here's my Objective-C Code

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1.0); 
NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"myFile.jpg\"rn\"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-streamrnrn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@--rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];


NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

and here's my PHP Script

```
if ($_FILES) {
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name);
} else {
    echo "No Files Found";   
}
```

Comment: You're quotes are messed up, you might want to fix that first. Also are all those `rn` suppose to be newlines because that looks wrong.

Comment: `filename=\"myFile.jpg\"rn\"` Remove the `\\` at the end.

Comment: @Shahar Stills Not Working, I Think The Error is in the php code right !? :)

Comment: @YoussefGamal No it wasn't to fix your problem, it was just to fix your post because it was bothering me. But yeah the error is probably in the PHP file. `$_FILES['filename']` = is `filename` the name of the form? And what output are you getting?

Comment: @YoussefGamal What did you change?